# Problems encountered when developing apps with Android 14

Tags: android, dex, android-securityexception, android-14

I found that after my app reached a fair size (e.g. by adding multiple libraries), running the app threw java.lang.SecurityException: writable dex file '.../code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex' is not allowed.

If I then remove most of the libraries leaving only those that were added by default, and run again, it could work. But then if I add a tiny bit of code, like a log, it could fail with the same error.

If I want it to run without this error, I have to uninstall the app and then run again from Android Studio. This is very inconvenient, because every time I make some changes, I have to uninstall the app. I wouldn't imagine anyone would like to develop Android apps like this.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe try using MultiDex?

Comment: why did you tag android-14? is this something specifically related to that OS?

Comment: @Lino Because the problem I am having is only on Android 14. Earlier Android versions work fine. Android 14 hasn't been released until August this year.

Comment: @WeiWen : Are you using Dynamic Code Loading (DCL) in your project or can you get info if the libraries are using this feature ?

Comment: @avinash I didn't use DCL. And I don't think any of the libraries that I included uses DCL. All of them are Android or google libraries, like navigation, lifecycle, material, etc.

Comment: Try turning off “build automatically “ in settings. https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/518884/question-1-i-m-starting-to-receive-this-error-more-and-more-#2d02f618-8363-43f8-993c-bef6cb2715ba

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I've been seeing it non-deterministically. The call chain seems to originate from native android OS code.

Comment: @Smalls No. I haven't found a solution. I am not actively developing any app on Android 14, just want to see what features there are. I am hoping google will find out the issue and fix it.

Comment: The issue seems to not be reproducible for me anymore without updating any of the libs I was using so the issue may have been resolved on the Android side.

Comment: Not sure if you have resolved the issue but in my case the issue was that I needed to update to java 11 and update the dependencies versions to newer ones.

Comment: @DPE  I updated Source Compatibility and Target Compatibility to version 11, and updated all the libraries to the latest. But still, even if I just add a print in code, I still get "Writable dex file is not allowed error".

Comment: same issue here, It's getting to the point that I feel I must update one dependency at a time and perform 3 hours of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also having this problem, so I took a look at this documentation [DexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader), and decided to do this.

```
package com.example

import android.app.Application

class BaseApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
         val dexOutputDir: File = codeCacheDir
         dexOutputDir.setReadOnly()
    }
}
```

Just putting `dexOutputDir.setReadOnly()` in my application solved the problem

Uninstall and reinstall the app again

Comment: This does not appear to fix the issue when the latest official play ads library writes a .jar file into /cache

Comment: Upgrade Android Studio version Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2 and this should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when testing my app on android 14 emulator. `DexClassLoader` is only allowed to use a readonly dex file. So I add `File("path/to/abc.dex").setReadOnly()` before `DexClassLoader` to solve my issue.

From your log `../code_cache/.../classes2.dex`, some kind of dex loading probably used in your code or dependencies. So you should make these dex files readonly before they are loaded.

Comment: where do I add the code: File("...").setReadOnly()?

Comment: before where you use DexClassLoader or just at Application / Activity onCreate.

Comment: I updated Android Studio. When I had the problem, I used Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1. Now I updated to Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 and I no longer have the problem. Maybe after I installed the old Android Studio version back, I will test your suggested solution.

Comment: Seeing a similar error when building with Iguana 2023.2.1 - the error appears  in the pre-launch report and the app is apparently writing a jar to the app's /cache folder.  No idea what that is about as no jar is being explicitly written by the app but may be written by com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite (?!)

Comment: @bilabila I tested adding your suggested code, but I still got "Writable dex file is not allowed" error. I tried to add the code in onCreate method of both the activity and the application classes. But neither one worked. The path I tried is something like this: ../code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex, assuming the full path that Android Studio pointed to is: /data/data/com.example.testandroid14/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex

Comment: did anyone solved it?