# Android Studio: App crashes without Error in Code

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

My app crashes on my phone when I click "run." Clearing the app cache on the phone resolves the issue. A restart always works as well, but if I make a minor code change (for example, just adding a new line), the app crashes again.

The error message I receive is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hoerspielduell, PID: 337
java.lang.SecurityException: Writable dex file '/data/data/com.example.hoerspielduell/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex' is not allowed.
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:406)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:128)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:438)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:387)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:160)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:130)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:146)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:93)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:134)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:126)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:61)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:1034)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1126)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1374)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3324)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3316)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6889)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2237)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8223)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:977)
```

I hope, that anybody could help me.

I have already tried "Clean Project" and "Rebuild Project," as well as uninstalling the app on the phone. I was expecting these actions to resolve the issue, but unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems encountered when developing apps with Android 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498531/problems-encountered-when-developing-apps-with-android-14)

Comment: The error is that you are trying to do something that isn't allowed anymore: loading DEX code and execute it from a writable position. New Android versions encore the security paradigm Write xor Execute. Where you can write you are not called to execute.